# Can't start XOrg during system boot

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg

After another system update unable to start XOrg on my computer.

I see the following lines in my `journalctl -b0`:

```
Jan 03 22:54:28 just-now-i9 gnome-session[2242]: gnome-session-binary[2242]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 03 22:54:28 just-now-i9 gnome-session-binary[2242]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 03 22:54:28 just-now-i9 at-spi-bus-launcher[2299]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jan 03 22:54:28 just-now-i9 at-spi-bus-launcher[2299]:       after 21 requests (19 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Video card drivers are installed:

```
just-now-i9@~$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver
ii  nvidia-driver-440                          440.44-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
```

```
just-now-i9@~$ nvidia-smi 
Fri Jan  3 23:45:09 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44       Driver Version: 440.44       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 26%   31C    P0     9W / 245W |      0MiB /  7979MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using the following linux distro and kernel:

```
just-now-i9@~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
just-now-i9@~$ uname -a
Linux just-now-i9 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg`:

```
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 238
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] usb 2-6: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.44  Sun Dec  8 03:38:56 UTC 2019
[Fri Jan  3 22:53:59 2020] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

I do not observe any significant issues inside `Xorg.logs`:

```
just-now-i9@~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.*.log | grep -E "(EE|WW)"
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    27.828] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    27.828] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    27.828] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    27.829] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    27.829] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    27.829] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    27.829] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    27.829] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    28.751] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    17.286] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    17.287] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    17.287] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    17.287] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    17.287] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    17.287] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    17.287] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    17.287] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    17.451] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  4392.536] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[  4392.536] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[  4392.536] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
```

Have seen nothing appropriate at `.xsession-errors`, `/var/crash/`.

Any idea how to debug/root cause/resolve this issue?